# Saving contact in device as well as google

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to save contacts in the device and Google both. Contact get added in device and Google both, but when I delete it from the device, its get deleted from Google also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save contacts programatically in Android device, you can follow this [Github repo.](https://github.com/sushantsomani2310/AndroidContactsAdd)

And to sync phone contacts and Google storage, you need to sync them under settings of the device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Contacts Sync Adapter. More details in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter).